# Mongodb: $unwind and compute $avg

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents storing IoT data. 
Following MongoDB [schema design best practices for IoT](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/time-series-data-and-mongodb-part-2-schema-design-best-practices), I came to documents with the following structure:

```
"_id" : "AQ106_2020-09-12T09",
"date" : "2020-09-12T09:00:00.000Z",
"station" : {
    "name" : "AQ106",
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            14.339263,
            40.814224
        ]
    },
    "properties" : {
        
    }
},
"samples" : [

        {
            "t" : ISODate("2020-09-12T11:02:00.000+02:00"),
            "data" : {
                "pm1_mg_m3" : 2.7,
                "pm2_5_mg_m3" : 4.6,
                "pm10_mg_m3" : 12,
                "P0" : 152,
                "P1" : 16,
                "P2" : 4.7,
                "P3" : 0.8,
                "P4" : 0.86,
                "P5" : 0.6,
                "P6" : 0.28,
                "P7" : 0.152,
                "P8" : 0.094,
                "P9" : 0.092,
                "P10" : 0.019,
                "P11" : 0,
                "P12" : 0,
                "P13" : 0.0188,
                "P14" : 0,
                "P15" : 0,
                "P16" : 0,
                "P17" : 0,
                "P18" : 0,
                "P19" : 0,
                "P20" : 0,
                "P21" : 0,
    
                    "P22" : 0,
                    "P23" : 0,
                    "temp_celsius" : 32.59,
                    "humRelPercent" : 34,
                    "press_mBar" : 1010.79,
                    "CO2mA" : 4,
                    "NO2_WE_mV" : 226.419,
                    "NO2_AE_mV" : 229.553,
                    "OX_WE_mV" : 252.287,
                    "OX_AE_mV" : 220.419,
                    "CO_WE_mV" : 509.077,
                    "AE_WE_mV" : 348.51,
                    "batt_V" : 13.5,
                    "source_V" : 17.6
                }
            },
            .... additional arrays
    }
```

Now I want to compute hourly or daily averages (or another metric) to populate a new collection with only summarised data.
I coded the following solution for hourly means:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {
  'station.name':'AQ104'
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$samples"
}}, {$group: {
  _id: "$date",
  P0: {
    $avg  : "$samples.data.P0"
  },
  temp:{
    $avg:"$samples.data.temp_celsius"
  }
  }}])
```

This works but I need to manually create a field for each property in `samples.data` in the original document and that's tedious. 
Moreover, how to group both by date and station.name?
You can find a working example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CodpMalPEhe).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the easy question, how to group on multiple fields? With a simple syntax change:

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: {
        date: "$date",
        station: "$station.name"
      }
}
```

Now for the second question this will be a bit more tedious. Mongo does not support "merging" objects by their keys with custom logic (in this case `$avg`). So we will have to convert the object to an array. unwind it, calculate the average per field and eventually group to restore the required structure like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "station.name": "AQ106"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$samples"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      objArr: {
        "$objectToArray": "$samples.data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$objArr"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        date: "$date",
        station: "$station.name",
        objKey: "$objArr.k"
      },
      value: {
        $avg: "$objArr.v"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          [
            {
              k: "$_id.objKey",
              v: "$value"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        date: "$_id.date",
        station: "$_id.station"
      },
      data: {
        "$mergeObjects": "$data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$data",
          "$_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nW7OOje3mc4)

------- EDIT ---------

For Mongo v4.4+ you can use [$accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/#grp._S_accumulator) which allows you to execute custom javascript code in your pipeline. I am unsure how this will fare against the native Mongo pipeline in terms of performance in scale.

One thing to note is that I added the initial `$addFields` stage under the assumption that different `samples` may have different keys. if this is not the case it is not needed.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      sampleKeys: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$samples",
              as: "sample",
              in: {
                $map: {
                  input: {
                    "$objectToArray": "$$sample.data"
                  },
                  as: "sampleArrItem",
                  in: "$$sampleArrItem.k"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            "$setUnion": [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      samples: {
        $accumulator: {
          init: function(keys){
            return keys.map(k => {return {k: {v: 0, c: 0}}});
          },
          initArgs: ["$sampleKeys"],
          accumulateArgs: ["$samples"],
          accumulate: function(state, sample){
            Object.keys(state).forEach((key) => {
              if (key in sample.data) {
                state[key].v += sample.data[key];
                state[key].c++;
              };
            });
            return state;
          },
          merge: function(state1, state2){
            Object.keys(state1).forEach((key) => {
              state1[key].v += state2[key].v;
              state1[key].c += state2[key].c;
            });
            return state1;
          },
          lang: "js"
        }
      }

    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObject: [
          "$samples",
          {station: "$station.name", date: "$date"},
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: thanks. I solved as below. I wonder if one could simplify the overall query using `mapReduce` or `$function`.

Comment: You can't really use `$function` to achieve and I feel using `mapReduce` is overkill on this use case, however if you're on v4.4 you can use `$accumulator`. Note that the current code's assumption is that the field `samples` exists even if it's an empty array. if this is not the case you need to add a check in the `init` function for it.

Answer (score 0):

I partially resolved my question in terms of grouping by multiple fields (MongoDB documentation was not so clear at this regard, in my opinion)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$samples"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        date: "$date",
        station: "$station.name"
      },
      P0: {
        $avg: "$samples.data.P0"
      },
      temp: {
        $avg: "$samples.data.temp_celsius"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lSFTIQJtYJy) the updated working example.

Thanks to Tom Slabbaert, I solved my question with the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$samples"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      objArr: {
        "$objectToArray": "$samples.data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$objArr"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        date: "$date",
        station: "$station",
        objKey: "$objArr.k"
      },
      value: {
        $avg: "$objArr.v"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          [
            {
              k: "$_id.objKey",
              v: "$value"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        date: "$_id.date",
        station: "$_id.station"
      },
      data: {
        "$mergeObjects": "$data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: "$_id.date",
      station: "$_id.station",
      data: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jBS6Aj0AEvO)

I wonder if it is possible to simplify the above solution using the new `$function` operator.
Thanks.